# Why isn't Date(2015, 11, 1) the first of December?

Tags: javascript, date

When I convert that date to ISO string I get the 30th of november 2015. Why wouldn't it be first of december? I have googled and I know that month is 0-indexed and that overflows lead to the next day/month/year. But I cannot explain myself that behaviour and when I google it I find unrelated topics.

Comment: Without seeing the code, best guess is that you live east of Greenwich and the ISO string is in UTC which is some hours behind your local time. Or the other way around.

Comment: [Cant relate](http://jsbin.com/fapiduruna/edit?console)

Comment: Please post the code you tried so we can evaluate it. Also review this post for pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 1):

Thing is if You type:

```
var date = new Date(2015, 11, 1);
console.log(date);
```

You will get output based on your timezone, for me it's:

```
Tue Dec 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

Function [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) will always output time in UTC. So in this case you will get this date minus one hour.

```
2015-11-30T23:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you'll see that:

> **Note:** Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent **local time**. If UTC is desired, use new `Date(Date.UTC(...))` with the same arguments.

Your users have different local timezones.
For me `new Date(2015, 11, 1)` gives `Tue Dec 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)` (I'm in the timezone Central European Time which is GMT+1).

Hence you can follow the MDN hint and use `Date.UTC` inside of your date call instead:

```
var date = new Date(2015, 11, 1);

console.log(date.toString());
// "Tue Dec 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)"
//                  00:00:00 in GMT+1 but 23:00:00 in GMT+0

console.log(date.toISOString());
// "2015-11-30T23:00:00.000Z"
//          ^^ 30th of november - that's a nogo!

var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 11, 1));

console.log(utcDate.toString());
// "Tue Dec 01 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time) 15:49:26.146"
//                  01:00:00 in GMT+1 but 00:00:00 in GMT+0

console.log(utcDate.toISOString());
// "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
//          ^^ The first! Not the 30th!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 11, 1));
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Output:

```
2015-12-01T02:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Actually no, the output is `2015-11-30T23:00:00.000Z` depending on your setup. You're not considering different user timezones.

Comment: Well, according to [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), " The timezone is always zero UTC offset"

Comment: Yes but the _passed_ value is local time if you look at the MDN article for Date.

Comment: Uhm .. what? I just want to set a date in javascript, is it for real that I have to worry about timezones? EDIT: my timezone is Berlin / Germany

Comment: Updated my answer. You can create UTC date instead of local.

Comment: I'm really surprised that it doesn't behave as you would expect. I think Date(x,y,z) should just return the date that you've specified ... what's the reasoning behind this? Why wouldn't you just return the date that the user has requested?

Comment: Because the "toISOString()" treat every date as UTC

Comment: @user3182532 If you don't want to worry about timezones, operate in local time. Don't use the ISO time which is UTC by definition. The reason it takes timezones into account is, well, because they exist. Midnight in Berlin is 11 PM in London.

Comment: ohhhh gosh of course, sorry. Now I've clicked. Of course it makes sense that I get this output if I convert to _ISO_ ! Using .toString() now instead ;)